# Table Compression

Tags: sql-server

If I create a table like

```
Create table test
( value int,
  value2 int
) 
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
```

and after executing this create table command I alter table to create a clustered index on this table say

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_test
ON test (value);
```

Would the table/clustered index will still be in PAGE Compression mode or mode will be changed to NONE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Still PAGE compression.

From the BOL article about [Data Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx):

> When a clustered index is created on a heap, the clustered index
>   **inherits** the compression state of the heap unless an alternative
>   compression state is specified.